# Passing a form from one controller's view to a completely different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, form-for

Ok I have searched the other Stackoverflow questions available, tried as best I can to decipher this problem, but I am at an impass. Im a PHP developer but I am just learning Ruby on Rails (Rails 4).

What I want to try achieve:
- POST a form (using form_for) that is residing in a view index.html.erb file residing under the family of "Blog" (so the controller is also called Blog)
- But I want that form to POST to a completely different controller, not the Blog controller, but a controller called Feature (specifically, to the create action in the controller called Feature)

I know I am supposed to use the :url component in form_for but I am certain the syntax I am typing out is wrong OR something else somewhere else is causing the error.

Forgive my newbie cluelessness at this I am just starting out in Rails

The error message I am getting currently:

ArgumentError in Blog#index
wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)
Extracted source (around line #3):

```
<h1>Blog main page, welcome</h1>

<% form_for :feature, @feature, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f| %>
<p>
<%= f.label :subject %><br>
<%= f.text_field :string %>
```

The code I have:

Index.html.erb (sitting under the Blog family)

```
<h1>Blog main page, welcome</h1>

<% form_for :feature, @feature, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :subject %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :string %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :author %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :string %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :string %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<br>

<%= link_to "My Blog", new_blog_path %>
```

The code I have for the Feature controller

```
class FeatureController < ApplicationController

    def index
    end

    def new

    end

    def show

    end

    def create

        @feature = Blog.new (feature_params)
        render text: params[:feature].inspect

    end

private

    def feature_params
        params.require(:feature).permit(:title, :text, :text2, :text3)
    end

end

end
```

The code I have sitting in my routes config

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  root 'blog#index' 

  resources :blog
  resources :admin
  resources :feature


end
```

My database schema looks like this:

```
  create_table "blogs", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "subject"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "author"
    t.text     "text"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
```

I have no clue what I am doing wrong :( If anyone is able to help me out I would be immensely appreciative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After amending the routes to use plural format, the solution is:

```
<%= form_for :features, :url => features_path do |f| %>
```

`features_path` being a path helper method for `'/features'`

Comment: That didnt work either :( error I got is undefined local variable or method `features_path'

Comment: @Kalcoder In that case,you have to set the routes correctly

Comment: I have included my routes config file in my question.... can you see what I am doing wrong by any chance? :(

Comment: `features_path` is just a helper that should be available looking at your routes file. Alternatively, `:url => '/features'`

Comment: Ah..... something different now....getting close maybe... error now is No route matches [POST] "/features"

Comment: changed it to :url => '/feature' (no s on the end of that, and I can post a form, but the error now is syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input, which I think maybe means the tag words in the form need changing

Comment: `resources :feature` should be `resources :features`, as should all your other resources be in plural format.

Comment: Just realised as a total total n00b move I mixed up my generated controller names not being plural, so after having seen you mention about resources needing to be plural it all fell into place and after a few other bug fixes I finally got it to work woohoo! Thanks :) The line that ended up working for this specific key issue was "<%= form_for :features, :url => '/features', method: :post do |f| %>"

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working. I'll update the answer to reflect comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `=` sing in your `form_for` tag.I suppose this caused the error.

It should be like this

```
<%= form_for :feature, @feature, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f| %>
```

Comment: Huh, so I did..... just tried it with the equal in it, still getting wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2) :(